# Netmiko commit method is not committing and do not exit from config mode

Tags: python, automation, cisco, sdn, netmiko

I am new netmiko library but the documentation seems to be fairly straight forward, not sure what I am missing in my code (or a bug i am not sure) that is not letting the commit go through on Cisco ios.

```
device = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios",
                                host="cisco-lab-device",
                                username="admin",
                                password="passwd",
                                session_timeout=120,
                                verbose=True)
                                #session_log="output.txt")
cmdlist = ['vrf new']
try:
    result = device.send_config_set(cmdlist,exit_config_mode=False)
    print("Result after sending commands ", result)
except Exception as err:
    device.disconnect()
    return

result = device.commit()
print('DONE') # I dont see this print at all
device.disconnect()

##This is the dump upon running the code:

Result after sending commands

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:cisco-lab-device#

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:cisco-lab-device#

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:cisco-lab-device#configure terminal

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:cisco-lab-device(config)#vrf new

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:cisco-lab-device(config-vrf)#
```

As I mentioned above, i dont see the print trace that i added after commit method. And also I checked show running-config on cisco box looks like the commit didnot go through and new vrf creation is not reflected. I tried with bunch of other commands as well its stuck at the same point. Can someone please shed some light what I could be missing here??

Comment: Please use `cisco_xr` instead of `cisco_ios`. The latter has no candidate configuration concept to be committed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build on this code.

It is simple code that will take device ip, username, password and device-type. It will connect to device and send commands you type in config_commands list. It will send commands and print you the output. And you can sand single command, just put it in send_command("example_command")

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
RTR_150 = {
    'ip':   '150.154.1.10',
    'username': 'test',
    'password': 'test',
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**RTR_150)

config_commands = [ 'int lo0',
                    'ip add 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0',
                    'no shut' ]
output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
print(output)

output = net_connect.send_command('show ip int brief')
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I figure out that device_type should be cisco_xr not cisco_ios. Its XR after all, which I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment from Tes3awy your device is running Cisco IOS XR, vs vanilla Cisco IOS.  The latter has no concept of a commit operation so device.commit() is not a valid operation.

So you need to change:

```
device_type="cisco_ios"
```

To:

```
device_type="cisco_xr"
```

Additional info:  Cisco IOS has no concept of a commit operation - commands take effect immediately when entered.  Hence, no commit() function needs to be implemented.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This config could help you :

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

RTR_150 = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "host": "router01",
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "secret": "secret_if_you_need"}

with ConnectHandler(**RTR_150) as net_connect:
    config_commands = [ "int loo 0",
                        "ip add 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0",
                        "no shut",
                        "do show ip int brief"]

    net_connect.enable()
    output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
    net_connect.disconnect()
    
    print(output)
```